# Using isset() or input_filter() as a conditionals

Tags: php, forum

I'm trying to determine if sanitization is necessary when checking for superglobal initialization. In my case the $_GET['reply'] variable isn't meant isn't meant to be used for user input into the database, but I make its use possible for hotlinking a page on the database. Like this `http://******.com/forum.php?reply=123`, but `forum.php` takes more than one variable but only one at a time. It takes `$_GET['post']`, `$_GET['tag']`, or  `$_GET['search'][]`. I have created three methods of checking for there initialization and wanted to determine which was best for the this type of situation in terms of speed and security.

Method #1:

```
if(isset($_GET['reply'])){
    $reply = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "reply");
    //display reply query
}
elseif(isset($_GET['post'])){
    $post = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "post");
    //display post query
}
elseif(isset($_GET['tag'])){
    $tag = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "tag");
    //display tag query
}
elseif(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "search"); 
    //display search query
    //$_GET['search'] is an array and I haven't figured out how properly filter it.
}
else{
    //display default query;
}
```

Method #2:

```
if(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "reply")){
        $reply = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "reply");
        //display reply query
    }
    elseif(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "post")){
        $post = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "post");
        //display post query
    }
    elseif(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "tag")){
        $tag = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "tag");
        //display tag query
    }
    elseif(filter_input(INPUT_GET, "search")){
        $search = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "search");
        //display search query
        //$_GET['search'] is an array and I haven't figured out how properly filter it.
    }
    else{
        //display default query;
    }
```

Method #3:

```
$reply = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "reply");
$post = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "post");
$tag = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "tag");
$search = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "search");
if($reply){ /* display reply query */ }
elseif($post){ /* display post query */ }
elseif($tag){ /* display tag query */ }
elseif($search){ /* display search query */ }
else{ /* display default query */ }
```

Comment: Security depends on what filter_input actually does, but #3 is more readable than the others.

Comment: With the exception of the `$_GET['search']` ,which is an array,  all the values should be integers but I'm not sure what filter I should use for that or if I should use one at all.

Comment: Method 3 seems a lot more readable. The other methods are redundant.

They are all fast and "secure", really. I would pick number 3. For the integer filters, I would recommend `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT`.